# TFS Online Git - CI build on specific folder checkin

Tags: git, msbuild, azure-devops

Is it possible to setup a CI build which is triggered only on a checkin(push) to a specific folder? I just found a way how to hook the build to a checkin to a specific branch.

We have one Git repository for all our products. Each Product has a subfolder in a Git Root. And such a project corresponds to a Team in VS and has its own SCRUM product backlog(http://geekswithblogs.net/Optikal/archive/2013/09/05/153944.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to do that.

You should split each of your products into it's own Git repository. The only separation that exists inside of a Git repo is for branches.

There are git commands to split folders off into their own repo with history.

**Update 2017**: You can add branch filters in VSTS now.

[image]

To only trigger on a single folder you would like have to exclude everything and then include only that folder.

Comment: Maybe at the time there were no Path filters on CI triggers in VSTS?